# jQuery Auto-Fill stop inside search

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I've got the jQuery autofill script working to populate my text box as the user types to recomend results.

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags,
open: function(event, ui) {
        $(".ui-autocomplete").css({
            'width' :   '600px'
        });
     }
});
});
```

What I need it to do is stop searching inside of the options and just search from the first letter.

For instance if an option is "Blue"  and the user types "Bl" then "Blue" should populate like it does, but I don't want the user to type in "ue" and have "Blue" appear as an option.

EDIT: based on the post below I'm trying this script but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Real Autocomplete</title>

<!-- jQuery UI  |  http://jquery.com/  http://jqueryui.com/  http://jqueryui.com/docs/Theming  -->
<style type="text/css">body{font:62.5% Verdana,Arial,sans-serif}</style>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    var matches = $.map( availableTags, function(tag) {
      if ( tag.toUpperCase().indexOf(request.term.toUpperCase()) === 0 ) {
        return tag;
      }
    });
    response(matches);
  }
});

</script>
</head>
<body>

  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this link on Jquery's forum:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/select-only-items-that-start-with-jquery-ui-autocomplete

one of the posters in that link provided this as an example:
http://jsbin.com/avoyu5/1/edit

If you type "sc" you will see that it works exactly how you want (it will not show you "javascript" but it will show you "scala")

Comment: I copied the script exactly but it doesn't seem to be working.  Not sure why it works at jsbin and not when I test it locally.

Comment: I've posted the script above @dseliahu